# Attempted to call function "wp" from the global namespace Symfony2 + Ekino Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, symfony, namespaces

I got this error on prod :

```
Attempted to call function "wp" from the global namespace
```

I'm using

Symfony 2.8 with ekino/wordpress-bundle dev-master

**The code is working fine on localhost both on prod and dev environement.**

Here is the wp-blog-header.php file (standard wordpress file)

```
<?php
/**
 * Loads the WordPress environment and template.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

if ( !isset($wp_did_header) ) {

    $wp_did_header = true;

    // Load the WordPress library.
    require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );

    // Set up the WordPress query.
    wp();

    // Load the theme template.
    require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/template-loader.php' );

}
```

If I comment `wp()` and `require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/template-loader.php' );` I don't have the error and I can reach the home page (but I probably gonna have some issues later).

The cache is cleared.
Capisfony run composer install just before, so the autoload file should be ok.

The exact error :

> [2016-07-05 12:51:37] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\UndefinedFunctionException:
>   "Attempted to call function "wp" from the global namespace." at
>   /var/www/blabla/releases/20160705104736/web/blog/wp-blog-header.php
>   line 16 {"exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\UndefinedFunctionException(code:
>   0): Attempted to call function \"wp\" from the global namespace. at
>   /var/www/blabla/releases/20160705104736/web/blog/wp-blog-header.php:16)"}
>   []

Any idea ? This is driving me crazy ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you have this error check you wp-config.php file.

In my case it was corrupted during the initial deployment process.
I regenerated it on the server and set the file as shared so capisfony won't overide it.

I hope this can help someone.